# dplyr:: Sum columns x1:x5 excluding column whose name == value of column y

Tags: r, dplyr

```
tibble::tribble(
             ~cell.name, ~cluster_label, ~cluster_id, ~X1, ~X2, ~X3, ~X4, ~X5,
     "GTACTTTAGCCAGTAG",       "Div_10",         "3",   0,   1,   2,   0,   0,
     "ACACTGAAGTCTCAAC",         "CR_1",         "1",  13,   1,   0,   1,   0,
     "GACGGCTCATCCTTGC",         "CR_1",         "1",  10,   1,   0,   1,   0,
     "CTCGAAAGTATAAACG",         "CR_1",         "1",  13,   0,   0,   0,   0,
     "GACGGCTGTCGCGTGT",         "CR_1",         "1",  10,   5,   0,   1,   0
)
```

I would like to get the sum of columns X1:X5, excluding, at each row, the column Xi where i == cluster_id.

**EDIT:**

**Expected output:**

```
tibble::tribble(
             ~cell.name, ~cluster_label, ~cluster_id, ~outliers,
     "GTACTTTAGCCAGTAG",       "Div_10",         "3",   1,
     "ACACTGAAGTCTCAAC",         "CR_1",         "1",   2,
     "GACGGCTCATCCTTGC",         "CR_1",         "1",   2,
     "CTCGAAAGTATAAACG",         "CR_1",         "1",   0,
     "GACGGCTGTCGCGTGT",        "Neu_2",         "2",   6
)
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: I think in the last row, you have 11 in expected, where it should be 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can reshape to 'long' format, get the `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("X")) %>% 
   group_by(rn, cell.name) %>%
   summarise(cluster_id = first(cluster_id), cluster_label = first(cluster_label),
        outliers = sum(value[readr::parse_number(name)!= cluster_id])) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-rn)
# A tibble: 5 x 4
#  cell.name        cluster_id cluster_label outliers
#  <chr>            <chr>      <chr>            <dbl>
#1 GTACTTTAGCCAGTAG 3          Div_10               1
#2 ACACTGAAGTCTCAAC 1          CR_1                 2
#3 GACGGCTCATCCTTGC 1          CR_1                 2
#4 CTCGAAAGTATAAACG 1          CR_1                 0
#5 GACGGCTGTCGCGTGT 1          CR_1                 6
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun! One thing I don't understand is why `group_by(cell.name AND name)`, instead of just grouping by `cell.name` ?

Comment: @gaelgarcia I guess you need only `group_by(cell.name)`, but because there was no expected output, i wasn't sure. thanks.  can you update with the expected output column

Comment: @gaelgarcia upon cehcking it again, it is an error from my part.  Sorry1

Comment: No worries - jsut updated the expected output. Thanks!